# Could not parse response: org.fusesource.restygwt.client.ResponseFormatException: Response was NOT a valid JSON document

Tags: json, rest, gwt, jersey, resty-gwt

Could not parse response: org.fusesource.restygwt.client.ResponseFormatException: Response was NOT a valid JSON document

I am getting the following errors in my code . 
I have added Defaults.setDateFormat(null); in onModuleload function.

```
14:16:42.441 [ERROR] [HelloWorld] Could not parse response: org.fusesource.restygwt.client.ResponseFormatException: Response was NOT a valid JSON document
org.fusesource.restygwt.client.ResponseFormatException: Response was NOT a valid JSON document
    at org.com.hello.shared.LoginInterface_Generated_RestServiceProxy_$1.parseResult(LoginInterface_Generated_RestServiceProxy_.java:34)
    at org.com.hello.shared.LoginInterface_Generated_RestServiceProxy_$1.parseResult(LoginInterface_Generated_RestServiceProxy_.java:1)
    at org.fusesource.restygwt.client.AbstractRequestCallback.onResponseReceived(AbstractRequestCallback.java:62)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:259)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:412)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:576)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:347)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor42.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.fusesource.restygwt.client.JsonEncoderDecoder$DecodingException: Expected a json string, but was given: {"email":"******@gmail.com", "password":"****"}
    at org.fusesource.restygwt.client.AbstractJsonEncoderDecoder$9.decode(AbstractJsonEncoderDecoder.java:187)
    at org.fusesource.restygwt.client.AbstractJsonEncoderDecoder$9.decode(AbstractJsonEncoderDecoder.java:1)
    at org.com.hello.shared.LoginInterface_Generated_RestServiceProxy_$1.parseResult(LoginInterface_Generated_RestServiceProxy_.java:32)
    at org.com.hello.shared.LoginInterface_Generated_RestServiceProxy_$1.parseResult(LoginInterface_Generated_RestServiceProxy_.java:1)
    at org.fusesource.restygwt.client.AbstractRequestCallback.onResponseReceived(AbstractRequestCallback.java:62)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:259)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:412)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:576)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:347)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor42.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you give the output JSON ?

Comment: @rjdkolb it seems from the exception that the json payload is : `{"email":"******@gmail.com", "password":"****"}`